# How can I declare TextView as global variable to use in other class

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am a new android dev. I want to use a same **TextView** in all activity. But, i don't know how to declare TextView as global Variable & How can i use this to show text in activity. Please help me. **The code is simple.**
Thank for every one.

Comment: if your layouts will be stored in xml file then you can use them anywhere in your application. You just need to inflate them and they wil be available to you.

Comment: Oh man! it's just not you think. I need to Change color with RadioButton & resize text too. then i want to known a code.

Answer (score 2):

Write your XML code of text view with id as:

```
<TextText
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Than in your activity declare it before onCreate() method as:

```
public static TextView textview = (TextView) findViewByID(Your ID);
```

Than this will be accessible to all calsses.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this everywhere:

```
TextView textview = (TextView) findViewByID(Your ID);
 textview = (TextView) findViewByID(Your ID);
```

Answer (score 1):

Make it a singleton. Or just keep one public static reference.

```
public class MyReference {
    public static TextView myTextView = new TextView();
}
```

and then you can use it anywhere by calling `MyReference.myTextView`

Comment: It mean i must create class for constant variable ? Because i have many activity in my app are use this textView. Before i use this, i have to import class too ?

Comment: Well I don't know about Android, but that's basic Java... And you don't have to create a class for this, you can put it in any meaningful one. But first I would encourage you to read any Java for beginner book :)

Answer (score -1):

I think this [Link](http://alinberce.wordpress.com/2012/02/20/android-edittext-with-custom-font-and-clear-button/) this is helpfull to

http://alinberce.wordpress.com/2012/02/20/android-edittext-with-custom-font-and-clear-button/

you have to create `Editbox` just One time & use anywhere in Application

weather use in `Layout` file or use Dynamically in java `Class`